# Detect if a character is Chinese character

Tags: xetex, unicode, xecjk

(XeLaTeX + XeCJK)

I am trying to translate an English document. I need to convert all '.' to '。' if the antecedent character is a Chinese character. I am using xstring to accomplish this object but I have no idea of detecting whether a character is Chinese one or not.

How to solve it?

Comment: Is there a range of code points in Unicode reserved for Chinese characters? (And welcome to TeX.SX!)

Comment: The CJK Unified Ideographs -block in Unicode is U+4E00 to U+9FCC (with extension blocks also U+20000-U+2FA10). You could maybe do something simple like `\def\isCJK#1{\ifnum\`#1>19968 is CJK\else not CJK\fi}`.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes. But I don't know how to get the unicode of a certain character. Maybe I should edit the question.

Comment: @morbusg so `\ifnum` works for a character? Thanks. I am a starter of XeLaTeX.

Comment: @user1526408: Note the backtick right after `\ifnum`, that is the thing that converts the character into its code point in base-10.

Comment: @morbusg it seems that backtick doesn't work for a variable. I have tried `\def \a {b}` and get the ASCII code of 'a'. Even if I define a "function" `\def check #1{...}` I couldn't make it.

Comment: @user1526408: you would need to first expand the `\a`, so `\expandafter\check\a`, or expand during definition; `\edef\b{c}`.

Answer (score 6):

Although it is possible to impletment it in `xeCJK`, using `\XeTeXinterchartoks`, I think it is much easier to solve the problem without TeX.

Say, you can search and replace the text in the editor. For example, in VIM, use

```
:%s/\([\u4E00-\u9FCC]\)\./\1。/g
```

to do the trick.